# Manually load large raster to perform lidR::locate_trees()

Tags: r, terra, lidr

I am attempting perform individual tree detection on a lidar-derived canopy height model raster using the lidR package in R.  The raster is approximately 2.5 Gb.  When I attempt to run the `locate_trees()` function, I get this error: `Error: Large on-disk rasters are not supported by locate_tree. Load the raster manually.`  What is meant by "loading the raster manually?" and how can I do this?  I made a reproducible example of my workflow.  However, making a fake >3GB raster may crash your R session or take forever.  Use caution before running:

```
library(lidR)
library(terra)

chm<-rast(xmin=-121.5, xmax =-120, ymin=44.5, ymax = 45.5, crs="EPSG:2992", nrows=150000, ncols=200000) #Fake 3 billion cell raster
values(chm)<-rnorm(3000000000, 20, 5) #giving random values to the raster cells

writeRaster(chm, paste(tempdir(), "CHM_Example.tif", sep="/"), filetype="GTiff")#writing the raster to disk

canopy<-rast(paste(tempdir(), "CHM_Example.tif", sep="/")) # reading the raster into R using the terra package framework

taos<-locate_trees(canopy, lmf(ws=5))#Error is thrown here attempting to perform individual tree detection
```

Comment: If you think your raster can fit in memory you can simply multiply by 1. `canopy = canopy*1`

Comment: That is brilliant JRR!  I think I have sufficient RAM that it should definitely be possible with a 2.5GB CHM raster.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remember that lidR will copy and convert it internally and will use memory to process it. So you need much more that 2.5 GB.

Comment: Point taken.  I ended up using my tiling-by-brute-force method below (partially because I found my old script before I saw your response and Robert's) and partially to ensure that I didn't have any memory issues and adapting your buffered chunk approach to a raster.  I love how clean Robert's approach is and would love to use it in the future but it doesn't allow for buffers. Am I being overly concerned about edge effects with my buffered tile approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dawned on me that I had run into this issue before...and solved it.  I dug up and dusted off an old script from a previous project, and voila the answer was there all along! "Loading the raster manually" means actually using the `readStart()`, `readValues()`, and `readStop()` functions in terra  to manually read all values within predetermined block of the raster to then feed to `lidR::locate_trees().`  I adapted the chunk and buffer scheme that @JRR in lidR into a loop to ensure I am getting full coverage without duplicates.  Admittedly, this is probably not the most efficient solution, but it works.

N.B.  in this reproducible example, I just use the Mixed Conifer dataset that comes with the lidR package

```
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(lidR)

LASFile<-system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las<-readLAS(LASFile)

dem<-rasterize_terrain(las)
norm<-las-dem
chm<-rasterize_canopy(norm)

writeRaster(chm, paste(tempdir(), "CHM_Example.tif", sep="/"), filetype="GTiff")#writing the raster to disk

Canopy<-rast(paste(tempdir(), "CHM_Example.tif", sep="/")) # reading the raster into R using the terra package framework

rws<-seq(1, nrow(Canopy), 5)
rws<-c(rws, nrow(Canopy))
cls<-seq(1, ncol(Canopy), 5)
cls<-c(cls, ncol(Canopy))
chunks_r<-length(rws)
chunks_c<-length(cls)
buff<-2
K<-1
cref<-crs(Canopy)


readStart(Canopy)

for(i in 1:(chunks_c-1)){
  
  xmn<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i])
  xmx<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i+1])
  
  if (i == 1){
    ncls<-(cls[i+1]+buff-cls[i])
    cread<-cls[i]
    xmnb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i])
    xmxb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i+1]+buff)
  }
  else{
    
    if (i == (chunks_c-1)){
      ncls<-(cls[i+1]+buff-cls[i])
      cread<-cls[i]-buff
      xmnb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i]-buff)
      xmxb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i+1])
    }
    else{
      
      ncls<-(cls[i+1]+buff+buff-cls[i])
      cread<-cls[i]-buff
      xmnb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i]-buff)
      xmxb<-xFromCol(Canopy, cls[i+1]+buff)
    }
  }  
  for(j in 1:(chunks_r-1)){
    
    ymx<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j])
    ymn<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j+1])
    
    if (j == 1){
      nrws<-(rws[j+1]+buff-rws[j])
      rread<-rws[j]
      ymxb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j])
      ymnb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j+1]+buff)
    } 
    else{
      
      if (j == (chunks_r-1)){
        
        nrws<-(rws[j+1]+buff-rws[j])
        rread<-rws[j]-buff
        ymxb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j]-buff)
        ymnb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j+1])
      }
      else{
        
        nrws<-(rws[j+1]+buff+buff-rws[j])
        rread<-rws[j]-buff
        ymxb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j]-buff)
        ymnb<-yFromRow(Canopy, rws[j+1]+buff)
      }
    }
    
    vals<-terra::readValues(Canopy, start=1, row=rread, nrows=nrws, col=cread, ncols=ncls)
    
    buff_ras<-rast(ymin=ymnb, ymax=ymxb, xmin=xmnb, xmax=xmxb, nrows=nrws, ncols=ncls, crs=cref, vals=vals)
    blank<-rast(ymin=ymn, ymax=ymx, xmin=xmn, xmax=xmx, nrows=nrws, ncols=ncls, crs=cref, vals=NA)
    blank_sf<-st_as_sf(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(blank)))
    
    if(any(!is.nan(vals))){
      out<-locate_trees(buff_ras, lmf(3, hmin = 10), uniqueness = "gpstime")
      ttops<-st_crop(out, blank_sf)
      fname<-paste(paste(tempdir(),"Gilchrist_itd_", sep="/"), K, ".gpkg", sep="")
      st_write(obj=ttops, dsn=fname, driver="GPKG", layer="tree_approx_obj", append=FALSE)
      K<-K+1
    }else
    {
      fname<-NULL
    }
    print(c(i, j,K))
  }
}

readStop(Canopy)

tmp<-list.files(tempdir(), pattern="*.gpkg", full.names = TRUE)

fxn<-function(X, fname){
  gpkg<-st_read(X)
  st_write(obj=gpkg, dsn=fname, layer="tree_approx_obj", append=TRUE)
}

taos<-lapply(tmp, fxn, fname=paste(tempdir(), "Example.gpkg", sep="/))
```

Answer (score 2):

The message means that lidR determined that it cannot load all the raster data into memory. One way to work around it is to use "tiles" (subsets), for example with `terra::makeTiles`

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
```

Make tiles. Do *not* use "30" for a big dataset like yours!

```
tiles <- makeTiles(r, 30)
```

If the output data is not very large you can do

```
out <- sapply(tiles, \(tile) {
        x <- rast(tile)
        taos <- lidR::locate_trees(x, lidR::lmf(ws=5))
        vect(taos)
    })

out <- vect(out)
```

Otherwise, it may be wise to write the output for each tile to disk. For example:

```
fout <- gsub(".tif", "_trees.shp", tiles)

for (i in 1:length(tiles)) {
    x <- rast(tiles[i])
    taos <- lidR::locate_trees(x, lidR::lmf(ws=5))
    writeVector(vect(taos), fout[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Robert!  This is a much simpler and more elegant solution than my brute-force tiling.  The one thing that makes me still lean to the brute force method below is being able to have a buffer around the tile for trees whose top pixel might be on the edge of the tile.  That may be more cautious than need be, and I will definitely keep this snippet of code for other large raster processes that can't natively lazy load.

Comment: The dev version now has an argument "buffer".

Comment: Excellent!! I will definitely use that in the future over my brute-force method.